# Div innerHTML rewrite failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've been glad for the help I've gotten with this table thing from my previous questions; but I have ran into another problem. The way that the word generator works for the tool is that it generates a random number from 1-9 using math.random then rounds it with math.floor. Then, with that, the `function changeRandom()` aspect of that code grabs that number and changes the number to a random word based on that number, so that if the random number generated is 3, it will turn into Word 3. Now, I tried to do the same thing for the answers, but it seems to not change. Only thing that the debugging console gives me as an error is that gen_nums isn't defined for the `getRandomAnswer()`, yet when I remove it, it takes longer to process + there's an error about max file space or something. I need to have something similar done with the word selector functions to apply with the 9 boxes. Here's the code.

**NOTE:** The notes/comments in the codes can be ignored, as they are for reference for when I present this.

## HTML

```
  <div id="randomizer">
    <div id="wordOutput">
      <div id="output">
        <p id="outputNumber"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="button">
        <!-- This is the button that calls the getRandom() function to create the word. --><button id="myBtn">Randomize!</button><br>
        <caption>Click this button to generate a random word!
        </caption>
        <!-- This is apart of the Randomizer tool, which can be changed to fit the words. It will output the answers based on  -->
        <div id="answers">
          <div class="output1" id="output1"></div>
          <div class="output2" id="output2"></div>
          <div class="output3" id="output3"></div><br>
          <div class="output4" id="output4"></div>
          <div class="output5" id="output5"></div>
          <div class="output6" id="output6"></div><br>
          <div class="output7" id="output7"></div>
          <div class="output8" id="output8"></div>
          <div class="output9" id="output9"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

## JavaScript

```
/*function playSound()  {

}
*/
/* This section is for the first tool; the Randomizer.*/
/* This is the new function for getting a random number; also used in the getRandomAnswer() function. To select different numbers, adjust the range. */
function getRandom() {
  var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  var gen_nums = [];

  function in_array(array, el) {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++) 
      if(array[i] == el) return true;
    return false;
  }

  function get_rand(array) {
    var rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
    if(!in_array(gen_nums, rand)) {
      gen_nums.push(rand); 
      return rand;
    }
    return get_rand(array);
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    return (get_rand(nums));
  }
}
function timeOut(){
  /* This can be ignored, as it was a testing function for creating, making, and fixing the randomizer tool, but may change based on creating new tools that need to be troubleshooted. */
  setTimeout (changeRandom, 1);
}
/* This is the function that grabs the innerHTML (what the box says) of the #output1 and changes that number to the word specified. [In example, if the number [randomly] generated was 5, then this function detects that the number was 5 and changes it to Word 5.]  */
function changeRandom()  {
  /* Using the "var x" command, this tells the function that whenever there's an x in the code, it will read it as "document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML", and will grab whatever is inside that #output1 element. */
  var x = document.getElementById('outputNumber').innerHTML
  /* Here's the tutorial for modifying this tool for the possible answers. This tool [by default] has it set to  */
  if(x == 1)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 1";
  } else if(x == 2)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 2";
  } else if(x == 3)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 3";
  } else if(x == 4)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 4" 
  } else if(x == 5) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 5"
  }
  else if(x == 6) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 6"
  } 
  else if(x == 7) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 7"
  }
  else if(x == 8) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 8"
  }
  else if(x == 9) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 9"
  }
  else if(x == 10) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 10"
  }
  /* If the function is broken [by user modifications], it will output "Error :c", which means the user should check their modifications. */
  else  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Error :c"
  }
}
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = getRandom(); changeRandom();})
function testFunction()  {
  if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML == 3)  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Three";
  }
  else  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "N3"
  }
}
function getRandomAnswer() {
  var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var copy = nums.slice();

  for (var i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    var rand = copy[ j ];

    // remove from array
    copy.splice(j, 1);

    // add to output
    document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = rand;
  }
  return gen_nums;
  document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = getRandomAnswer();
}
function changeRandomAnswer()  {
  /* Using the "var x" command, this tells the function that whenever there's an x in the code, it will read it as "document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML", and will grab whatever is inside that #output1 element. */
  /* Here's the tutorial for modifying this tool for the possible answers. This tool [by default] has it set to  */
  if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "1")  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Answer 1";
  }
  else if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "2")  {
    document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "Answer 2";
  } 
  else if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "3")  {
    document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = "Answer 3";
  } 
  else if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "4")  {
    document.getElementById("output4").innerHTML = "Answer 4" 
  } 
  else if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "5") {
    document.getElementById("output5").innerHTML = "Answer 5"
  }
  else if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "6") {
    document.getElementById("output6").innerHTML = "Answer 6"
  } 
  else if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "7") {
    document.getElementById("output7").innerHTML = "Answer 7"
  }
  else if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "8") {
    document.getElementById("output8").innerHTML = "Answer 8"
  }
  else if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "9") {
    document.getElementById("output9").innerHTML = "Answer 9"
  }
  /* If the function is broken [by user modifications], it will output "Error :c", which means the user should check their modifications. */
  else  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Error :c"
  }
}
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML = getRandomAnswer(); changeRandomAnswer();})
```

Here's a workable [codepen](http://codepen.io/TheGamingHideout/pen/JoPVZw) to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things the code you provided is doing that are unnecessary.

- On the last line, you dont need to assign an output from **getRandomAnswer()** to the innerHTML of "answers". The function itself is already performing the operation to assign the random numbers to each output. You can simply just call the function:
  `document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){ getRandomAnswer(); changeRandomAnswer();})`
- Within the function of **getRandomAnswer()**, you can remove `return gen_numbers;` and you can remove the line:
  `document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = getRandomAnswer();`
  This is causing the recursion and is completely not necessary since the numbers are getting applied in the for loop just before.

The function **changeRandomAnswer()** has some issues that need to be addressed:

- First off you are defining instead of comparing the contents of innerHTML within each if condition by using one equal sign(=) instead of two(==).
- The way you have the logic set up, it will only apply to the first box it matches and skip the rest. You are also only ever checking for the innerHTML value of "output1".

One solution is to loop through each element and run the same conditional check on each element:

```
function changeRandomAnswer()  {

  var answers = document.getElementById("answers");

  for(var i = 0, len = answers.children.length; i < len; i++) {
    var output = answers.children[i];
    var answer = output.innerHTML;

    if(answer == "1")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 1";
    }
    else if(answer == "2")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 2";
    } 
    else if(answer == "3")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 3";
    } 
    else if(answer == "4")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 4" 
    } 
    else if(answer == "5") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 5"
    }
    else if(answer == "6") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 6"
    } 
    else if(answer == "7") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 7"
    }
    else if(answer == "8") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 8"
    }
    else if(answer == "9") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 9"
    }
    else  {
      output.innerHTML = "Error :c"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the full javascript with all edits mentioned (Also I forked a working version on [codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwwbap)):

```
/*function playSound()  {

}
*/
/* This section is for the first tool; the Randomizer.*/
/* This is the new function for getting a random number; also used in the getRandomAnswer() function. To select different numbers, adjust the range. */
function getRandom() {
  var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  var gen_nums = [];

  function in_array(array, el) {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++) 
      if(array[i] == el) return true;
    return false;
  }

  function get_rand(array) {
    var rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
    if(!in_array(gen_nums, rand)) {
      gen_nums.push(rand); 
      return rand;
    }
    return get_rand(array);
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    return (get_rand(nums));
  }
}
function timeOut(){
  /* This can be ignored, as it was a testing function for creating, making, and fixing the randomizer tool, but may change based on creating new tools that need to be troubleshooted. */
  setTimeout (changeRandom, 1);
}
/* This is the function that grabs the innerHTML (what the box says) of the #output1 and changes that number to the word specified. [In example, if the number [randomly] generated was 5, then this function detects that the number was 5 and changes it to Word 5.]  */
function changeRandom()  {
  /* Using the "var x" command, this tells the function that whenever there's an x in the code, it will read it as "document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML", and will grab whatever is inside that #output1 element. */
  var x = document.getElementById('outputNumber').innerHTML
  /* Here's the tutorial for modifying this tool for the possible answers. This tool [by default] has it set to  */
  if(x == 1)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 1";
  } else if(x == 2)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 2";
  } else if(x == 3)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 3";
  } else if(x == 4)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 4" 
  } else if(x == 5) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 5"
  }
  else if(x == 6) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 6"
  } 
  else if(x == 7) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 7"
  }
  else if(x == 8) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 8"
  }
  else if(x == 9) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 9"
  }
  else if(x == 10) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 10"
  }
  /* If the function is broken [by user modifications], it will output "Error :c", which means the user should check their modifications. */
  else  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Error :c"
  }
}
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = getRandom(); changeRandom();})
function testFunction()  {
  if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML == 3)  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Three";
  }
  else  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "N3"
  }
}
function getRandomAnswer() {
  var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var copy = nums.slice();

  for (var i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    var rand = copy[ j ];

    // remove from array
    copy.splice(j, 1);

    // add to output
    document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = rand;
  }
  //return gen_nums;
  //document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = getRandomAnswer();
}
function changeRandomAnswer()  {

  var answers = document.getElementById("answers");

  for(var i = 0, len = answers.children.length; i < len; i++) {
    var output = answers.children[i];
    var answer = output.innerHTML;

    if(answer == "1")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 1";
    }
    else if(answer == "2")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 2";
    } 
    else if(answer == "3")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 3";
    } 
    else if(answer == "4")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 4" 
    } 
    else if(answer == "5") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 5"
    }
    else if(answer == "6") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 6"
    } 
    else if(answer == "7") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 7"
    }
    else if(answer == "8") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 8"
    }
    else if(answer == "9") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 9"
    }
    else  {
      output.innerHTML = "Error :c"
    }
  }

}
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){ getRandomAnswer(); changeRandomAnswer();})
```

Comment: Thanks, and I would voteup for the codepen usage but.. rep not 15 :P

Answer (score 1):

You having some scoping issue and a recursion issue. To simplify:

```
function foo() {
  var gen_nums = [];

  for ( var i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
    gen_nums.push(i)
  }

  return gen_nums;
}

function bar() {
  var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var copy = nums.slice();

  return gen_nums;
  bar()
}

console.log(foo()) // [0, ..., 9]
console.log(bar()) // error - gen_nums is not defined
```

The reason why removing it from `getRandomAnswer()` makes things take longer, is because when it is there, the function stops at that line, and not reaching the next line, which is

`document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = getRandomAnswer();`

which makes the function recursive.

Comment: The speed is 100% fine with the thing, its just its not actually rewriting the numbers in the block div, @elzi . I mentioned the gen_nums cause I thought it was a conflict with the rewrite.

Comment: I'm just telling your what your javascript is doing. It's not 100% fine when you're trying to return an undefined variable. It will error every time.

Answer (score 0):

Your getRandomAnswer Function is

```
function getRandomAnswer() {
  var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var copy = nums.slice();

  for (var i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    var rand = copy[ j ];

    // remove from array
    copy.splice(j, 1);

    // add to output
    document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = rand;
  }
  return gen_nums;
  document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = getRandomAnswer();
}
```

In this you are returning gen_nums before some code execution. So write it like,

```
function getRandomAnswer() {
  var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var copy = nums.slice();

  for (var i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    var rand = copy[ j ];

    // remove from array
    copy.splice(j, 1);

    // add to output
    document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = rand;
  }
    document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = getRandomAnswer();
  return gen_nums;

}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/s8wf6z6s/) is your working code in jsfiddle.

Comment: The speed is 100% fine with the thing, its just its not actually rewriting the numbers in the block div, @WisdmLabs . I mentioned the gen_nums cause I thought it was a conflict with the rewrite.